# Uneditable combobox in Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a userform using macros in excel.
The code is independent from excel (it does not read the data from excel).

Once the userform opens, I populate the combobox with few items in it by:

```
combo.additem "a" 
combo.additem "b" 
combo.additem "c"'
```

From what I found, in order to make the combobox uneditable, I need to change the style of the list to drop downlist.

However, once I have done so, my combobox options turns to be:

```
"" (blank cell)
a
b
c
```

Is there an option to keep the combobox uneditable without adding the first empty cell?

Thank you

Comment: The "empty" option is the equivalent to "nothing selected".  AFAIK, there is no way to avoid the option, in that it is the uninitialized state of a ComboBox with that style. I'd suggest just setting a default value if it's appropriate and handling the empty value with validation as required.

Comment: When you add 3 items to combobox as you mentioned, you do not get 4 option in the dropdown? How did you get those 4 options?

Comment: @Comintern What you suggest is that I create in Combo_Initialize Combo.value = "a" for example?

Comment: That was Siddharth's suggestion, but yes. Think of the empty option as "null".

Comment: @SiddharthRout I got 4 options (empty +3) and once the userform opens, after choosing an option it removes the empty one. It makes me bugs only at the first choose

Comment: that's what I thought. It should not give you a blank option when you click the dropdwon. I would like to understand how you are getting that. Otherwise In `UserForm_Initialize()` put this `Combo.ListIndex=0` and it will sort your problem

Comment: Let me get this straight. When the form launches, there is no value in the combobox (which is understood and expected) and then when you click the dropdown arrow, you see 4 options? One blank row and "a,b,c"? If yes then this is strange as you should not see 4 options...

Comment: No, I have an "opening screen" thats says hello lets continue. One i click the continue button on it(continue_Click has the userform2.combo.add item), it populates the combobox(which is on userform2 and not on the opening screen) with a,b,c and makes userform2.show to show me the userform with the combobox. However, once it is shown, it appears to have the 4 options I described before until I click on the combobox.

Comment: What do you mean "it appears to have"? Are you referring to the fact that dropdown has a blank value when it launches or do you actually see a blank row in the dropdown?

Comment: The dropdown has blank value, then I click on the arrow of the combobox and it shows empty+3 then once I click "a" for example and then the arrow of the combobox again, it already wont have the empty

Comment: `it shows empty+3` That should not happen :) Posisble to see your file?

Comment: When I change it to droplist down it basically remove text option..thats why it wont appear at first. Cant send the file atm, will do later.

Answer (score 0):

The combobox will become an uneditable dropbox when you change its <kbd>Style</kbd> to `2 - fmStyleDropDownList`.

Add `.ListIndex=0` to your code to make the dropbox come up with no empty field and have the first item displayed as the default.